# Netbeans IDE STL support

Tags: c++, list, netbeans, stl

Hello am new to Netbeans IDE for C++. I want support for STL collections like list, stack and all in netbeans. I am writing the following code in it and getting red line beneath 'list' word and message that unable to resolve identifier list. What should I do ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main ()
{
  std::list<int> first;
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT  : mentioned headers files I have included in my code.

Comment: ipc : have that included. edited my question above by including the headers files.

Comment: Try to go to Tools -> Options -> C/C++ -> Code Assistance and add the directory of STL library

Comment: Does the code compile though? The error detection the IDE does on the fly is not always reliable. What matters are compile errors, not red lines. :)

Comment: Ya it complied and ran successfully. I  thought it wouldn't as it showed red lines and am new to IDE.

Comment: GeraldSV : how to add/verify that code assistance has stl library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you made netbeans project the following way?
File -> New Project .. -> C/C++ -> C/C++ Application

I did this way, pasted your code in main.cpp and could compile without errors.

(Netbeans 7.2.1)

Comment: Ya it complied and ran successfully. I thought it wouldn't as it showed red lines and am new to IDE.

Comment: Red line should show error, Yellow should show warning, but netbeans sometimes make fake error and warning messages.